# computational expression indentation confusion

Tags: f#

I clearly don't understand indentation in computational expression (I'm usually a map/bind sort of person).

This code compiles

```
        seq {
            for concept in model.EsWondomainmodelconcepts do
                let attLookup = seq {
                    for att in concept.Attributes.EsWondomainmodelattributes do
                        for tag in (att.XmlTag |> Option.toArray) do
                            for mult in (att.Multiplicity.EspEnumeration.Identificationdisplaystring.String |> Option.toArray) do
                                (tag,multiplicityToRelationshipCardinality mult)
                } 
                (concept.XmlTag, attLookup |> Map.ofSeq)
        }
        |> Map.ofSeq
        |> WOnSchemaRawData
```

this doesnt

```
        seq {
            for concept in model.EsWondomainmodelconcepts do
                let attLookup = seq { // FS3118 on this line
                    for att in concept.Attributes.EsWondomainmodelattributes do
                        for tag in (att.XmlTag |> Option.toArray) do
                            for mult in (att.Multiplicity.EspEnumeration.Identificationdisplaystring.String |> Option.toArray) do
                                (tag,multiplicityToRelationshipCardinality mult)
                } |> Map.ofSeq // FS0588 here
                (concept.XmlTag, attLookup)
        }
        |> Map.ofSeq
        |> WOnSchemaRawData
```

the line "let attLookup = ...." complains

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   FS3118  Incomplete value or function definition. If this is in an expression, the body of the expression must be indented to the same column as the 'let' keyword.
```

and the 1st "|> Map.ofSeq" complains

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   FS0588  The block following this 'let' is unfinished. Every code block is an expression and must have a result. 'let' cannot be the final code element in a block. Consider giving this block an explicit result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I understand this without trying it out with a compiler. I will illustrate what I think happens with some simpler code snippets.

This is allowed:

```
let x = seq { 1; 2;
    3 }
```

But this is not allowed, and it makes sense to me why not:

```
let x = seq { 1; 2;
    3 }
    |> Seq.sum
```

This is allowed, which also makes sense to me:

```
let x =
    seq { 1; 2;
        3 }
    |> Seq.sum
```

So I suspect you can format the code as in the last snippet, and it'll be good.